# get List of recently added .csv Files into the directory using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a output files folder, where all the files get dumped, i need to check into the folder every five mins and pick up all the list of recently added files by using python.

One way of doing this is using sets, and get the non intersected files, is there any other better approach?

much appreciate the code snippet of it.

Thanks

Comment: You can check modification times of files maybe...but really your description is kind of vague. Is this a homework assignment or a real world problem?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you can make use of the particular method `listdir()` from the `os` module and `sleep()` from the `time` module.

```
import os
from time import sleep

path = "/path/to/folder/with/csv/files"

with open("log.txt", "a+") as log_file:
    while True:
        log_file.seek(0)
        existing = [f.strip() for f in log_file]

        csvs = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".csv") and f not in existing]

        if len(csvs) > 0:
            print(f"Found {len(csvs)} new file(s):")
            for f in csvs:
                print(f)
            print("\n")
        else:
            print("Found 0 new files.")

        log_file.writelines([f"{f}\n" for f in csvs])

        sleep(300)
```

We will be storing the existing file names in a `.txt` file. You could use a `.json` file or any other file type you like. Firstly, we open the file using `with/open` (in append/read mode) and get a list of the file names that have previously been stored in the text file. We then get a list of all of the `.csv` files in that directory that are not in the file:

```
csvs = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".csv") and f not in existing]
```

`os.listdir()` is lists all of the files and folders in the current working directory.

The following `if/else` statement is simply for output purposes and is not required. It is only saying: *if new csv files were found, print how many and the names of each. If none were found, print that zero were found*.

All that's left to do is write the newly discovered file names into the `.txt` file so that on the next iteration, they will be marked as existing and not new:

```
log_file.writelines([f"{f}\n" for f in csvs])
```

The final line, `sleep(300)`, makes the program wait 300 seconds, or 5 minutes, to iterate again.